# Passing class instantiations (layering)

Tags: python, database, oop, python-3.x

Program design:

- Class A, which implements lower level data handling

  - Classes B-E, which provide a higher level interface to A to perform various functions

    - Class F, which is a UI object that interacts with B-E according to user input

There can only be one instantiation of A at any given time, to avoid race conditions, data corruption, etc.

What is the best way to provide a copy of A to B-E? Currently F instantiates A and holds onto it for the life of the program, passing it to B-E when creating them. Alternately I could create a globally available module with a shared copy of A that everything uses. Another alternative is to make B-E subclasses of A, but that violates the constraint of only one A (since each subclass would be their own data handler, so to speak).

Language is Python 3, FWIW.

Comment: Someone should've suggested overloading `__new__`. That would've been a more efficient way to do it than having all instances of `A` share a dict.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [Borg](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/66531-singleton-we-dont-need-no-stinkin-singleton-the-bo/) instead of a Singleton.

```
>>> class Borg( object ):
...     __ss = {}
...     def __init__( self ):
...             self.__dict__ = self.__ss
...
>>> foo = Borg()
>>> foo.x = 1
>>> bar = Borg()
>>> bar.x
1
```

Comment: Interesting. So I would assume that I would make A a subclass of Borg, then B-E subclasses of A? Nice.

Comment: @bk0: well, Borg isn't a specific class so much as a design pattern; you would make `A` (whatever class it is) "Borglike" by making each instance's `__dict__` be a class variable (and therefore shared between instances). Don't subclass `A` for this; just make a new instance whenever you want one and it will magically share state with all the other instances.

Answer (score 0):

How about using the module technique, this is much simpler.

in module "A.py"

```
class A(object):
   def __init__(self, ..)
       ...
a = A()
```

in module "B.py"

```
from A import a

class B(object):
   def __init__(self)
       global a
       self.a = a
```

The both have single instance a.

The same could be done for other classes C, D, F etc

Comment: Using 'global' turns my stomach. I've effectively done something similar though using 'shared.py' where F assigns an instantiation of A which gets picked up by B-E.